# How can I add another offer to the function

Tags: javascript

I am a Javascript learner. I am practicing Javscript object properties and methods.
I want to add another offer to Black pen suppose it will be "10%", how should I go further. Please help.
Is this the correct way of writing code?

```
function pen(color, size, price) {
    this.color = color;
    this.size = size;
    this.price = price;
}

var pen1 = new pen("Red", "Medium", 20);
var pen2 = new pen("Black", "Large", 35);
var pen3 = new pen("Pink", "Small", 20);

pen.prototype.offer = function() {
    return "12%";
}

console.log("You have choosen " + pen1.color + " pen with " + pen1.size + " size. And its price is Rs." + pen1.price);
console.log("You have choosen " + pen2.color + " pen with " + pen2.size + " size. And its price is Rs." + pen2.price);
console.log("You have choosen " + pen3.color + " pen with " + pen3.size + " size. And its price is Rs." + pen3.price + " with " + pen3.offer() + " offer");
```

Comment: You can overwrite the offer function just for Black: `pen2.offer = function(){ return "10%"; }`

Comment: `function pen(color, size, price) {
    this.color = color;
    this.size = size;
    this.price = price;
    this.offer = offer;
}`

Comment: `pen.prototype.offer` will always return __12%__ as it is hard coded.. You must have `offer` property associated with the `pen` object..

Comment: okay thanks @Rayon. So I have to add offer property to pen object itself. Thank you :)

Comment: @maheshv13, I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify pen2 offer function

```
pen2.offer = function(){ return parseInt(pen.prototype.offer()) + 10 +"%" ; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably by now you have already got your answer.Here is just another way to explore the prototype

Let use assume that ***pen*** is a ***stationary*** item.A stationary item can also be a *book* , a *ruler* ,a *scale* and so on.So it is safe to assume that *stationary* can be a parent object

And *pen*,*ruler*,*book* etc can be child of stationary. & child object can inherit properties.In javascript it is prototype based inheritance.

```
    function Stationary(){
     //See there is no options provided here
    }
    // Adding showItem & offers method to Stationary prototype property
    Stationary.prototype.showItem = function(){
        console.log("You have choosen " +this.item +" with " +this.color + " having "+ this.size + " size "+". And its price is Rs." 
                        + this.price +" with "+this.offers(this.offer) +" offer");
    }

    Stationary.prototype.offers = function(offer){
      if(offer){
        return offer;   
      } 
      else{
        return "No offer";
      }
    }

   // Creating an object with some property
    var _p1Options ={
       item:"Pen",
       color:"Indigo",
       size:"Large",
       price:25,
       offer:'12%'
    }


    //Creating a function which will accept the options
    function Item (options){
        this.item = options.item || "default";
        this.color = options.color || "default";
        this.price = options.price || "default";
        this.size = options.size || "default";
        this.offer = options.offer || "default";
    }

    //Setting Item's prototype to Stationary's constructor
    // It will allow us to inherit all the properties
    Item.prototype = new Stationary();
    //Create a _p1 object with Item constructor
    var _p1 = new Item(_p1Options);
    //Item does not have showItem property,it will inherit from Stationary
    console.log(_p1.showItem());
```

So to answer your question you can just create an object like `_p1Options` & assign property values(including offer) you want instead of hard coding the return value.

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyrm1aud/) for more

Comment: Thank you very much @user2181397. This will really help me to understand the inheritance and use of prototype properties. :)